# Is conditional operator (?:) with two instances of classes convertible to arithmetic/pointer type valid in C++?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Reading The Standard, I see only paragraphs that it should compile either when both are arithmetic or when both are pointer types or when types are implcitly convertible to one another. However I don't see why types convertible to arithmetic/pointer types should perform this conversion. Am I missing something?
Here's an example which compiles by newest g++/clang++:

```
struct A { operator int () const { return 0; }};
struct B { operator int () const { return 0; } };

int f ()
{
  A x; B y;
  return true ? x : y;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/g/U3DfUX

Comment: @Holt Ha, that's about as duplicate as you can get :)

Comment: Sorry for my bad search skills!